# How do I put sets or arrays in a two-dimensional Ruby hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, set

I want to create a two dimensional hash for holding sets in Ruby. I expect the following code to hold four different sets and also to be able to list the keys in the first dimension of the hash.

```
require 'set'

cities = Hash.new()
cities['Europe'] = Hash.new(Set.new)
cities['Asia'] = Hash.new(Set.new)

cities['Europe']['Sweden'].add "Stockholm"
cities['Europe']['Sweden'].add "Gothenburg"
cities['Europe']['Denmark'].add "Copenhagen"
cities['Europe']['Denmark'].add "Odense"

cities['Asia']['Japan'].add "Tokyo"
cities['Asia']['Japan'].add "Kyoto"
cities['Asia']['China'].add "Beijing"
cities['Asia']['China'].add "Shanghai"

p cities['Europe']
p cities['Asia']

p cities['Europe']['Sweden']
p cities['Asia']['Japan']
```

I get the following output:

```
{}
{}
#<Set: {"Stockholm", "Gothenburg", "Copenhagen", "Odense"}>
#<Set: {"Tokyo", "Kyoto", "Beijing", "Shanghai"}>
```

It seems like the underlying implementation of hashes and sets interfere  with each other and I get this unintuitive result. If instead of sets use arrays (i.e. replace `Set.new` with `Array.new` and replace `.add` with `.push`) I get the same, unwanted, result.

(Ruby version: ruby 2.3.1p112)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing `h = Hash.new(Set.new)`, then the default value that is returned when accessing keys that do not exist in the hash will be the instance of `Set`, meaning the same set is shared. You can check it this way:

```
h = Hash.new(Set.new)
h["Sweden"] << "Stockholm"
# => #<Set: {"Stockholm"}>
h["Denmark"] << "Copenhagen"
# => #<Set: {"Stockholm", "Copenhagen"}>
h["Sweden"].object_id == h["Denmark"].object_id
# => true
```

Also it returns the default value when accessing keys that do not exist in the hash, meaning that the hash is not populated when accessing it.

```
h = Hash.new(Set.new)
h["Sweden"]
# => #<Set: {}>
h
# => {}
```

You can specify a block well calling [`Hash.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new). The block will get called with the hash and the key when accessing a key that does not exist in the hash. The block should return the default value. This is where you can store a different instance of `Set` in the hash, like so:

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Set.new }
h["Sweden"] << "Stockholm"
# => #<Set: {"Stockholm"}>
h["Denmark"] << "Copenhagen"
# => #<Set: {"Copenhagen"}>
h
# => {"Sweden"=>#<Set: {"Stockholm"}>, "Denmark"=>#<Set: {"Copenhagen"}>}
```

You can combine them to avoid setting a hash for each continent:

```
cities = Hash.new do |continents, continent_name|
  continent_countries = Hash.new { |countries, country_name| countries[country_name] = Set.new }
  continents[continent_name] = continent_countries
end
cities["Europe"]["Sweden"] << "Stockholm"
cities["Europe"]["Denmark"] << "Copenhagen"
cities["Asia"]["Japan"] << "Tokyo"
cities["Asia"]["Japan"] << "Kyoto"
cities
# => {"Europe"=>{"Sweden"=>#<Set: {"Stockholm"}>, "Denmark"=>#<Set: {"Copenhagen"}>},
#  "Asia"=>{"Japan"=>#<Set: {"Tokyo", "Kyoto"}>}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is...

```
cities['Europe'] = Hash.new(Set.new)
cities['Asia'] = Hash.new(Set.new)
```

... for each key you are setting the default to be the same object (an instance of Hash.new) and that object is the same object for every member of cities['Europe']. Plus using `.add` does not really instantiate the hash key, just adds to the underlying default `Set`.

You can use a block instead which will work fine... but you'll need to explicity store the default, in the block, to the hash.

```
cities['Europe'] = {|hash, key| hash[key] = Set.new}
cities['Asia'] = {|hash, key| hash[key] = Set.new}
```

Bonus suggestion...

You can create the `cities` hash with nested Hash.new blocks, in such a way that you don't need to explicitly create the hash for each continent...

```
cities = Hash.new{|hash,key| hash[key] = Hash.new{|country_hash, country| country_hash[country] = Set.new } }
```

giving you...

```
require 'set'

cities = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = Set.new}}

cities['Europe']['Sweden'].add "Stockholm"
cities['Europe']['Sweden'].add "Gothenburg"
cities['Europe']['Denmark'].add "Copenhagen"
cities['Europe']['Denmark'].add "Odense"

cities['Asia']['Japan'].add "Tokyo"
cities['Asia']['Japan'].add "Kyoto"
cities['Asia']['China'].add "Beijing"
cities['Asia']['China'].add "Shanghai"

p cities['Europe']
=> {"Sweden"=>#<Set: {"Stockholm", "Gothenburg"}>, "Denmark"=>#<Set: {"Copenhagen", "Odense"}>}
p cities['Asia']
=> {"Japan"=>#<Set: {"Tokyo", "Kyoto"}>, "China"=>#<Set: {"Beijing", "Shanghai"}>}

p cities['Europe']['Sweden']
=> #<Set: {"Stockholm", "Gothenburg"}>
p cities['Asia']['Japan']
=>#<Set: {"Tokyo", "Kyoto"}>
```